# Is my method of fetching MySql data using prepared statements inefficient and taxing on my server?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli, prepared-statement

I was informed by someone senior in our company today that the PHP code I have written for performing prepared statements on a MySQL database is "inefficient" and "too taxing on our server". Since then I find myself in the difficult position of trying to understand what he meant and then to fix it. I have no contact to said person for four days now so I am asking other developers what they think of my code and if there are any areas that might be causing bottlenecks or issues with server performance.

My code works and returns the results of my query in the variable $data, so technically it works. There is another question though as to whether it is efficient and written well. Any advice as to what that senior employee meant or was referring to? Here is the method I use to connect and query our databases.

(Please note, when I use the word method I do not mean a method inside a class. What I mean to say is this how I write/structure my code when I connect and query our databases.)

```
<?php

// Create database object and connect to database
$mysqli=new mysqli();
$mysqli->real_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

// Create statement object
$stmt=$mysqli->stmt_init();

// Prepare the query and bind params
$stmt->prepare('SELECT `col` FROM `table` WHERE `col` > ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $var1);

// Execute the query
$stmt->execute();

// Store result
$stmt->store_result();

// Prepare for fetching result
$rslt=array();
$stmt->bind_result($rslt['col']);

// Fetch result and save to array
$data=array();
while($stmt->fetch()){
    foreach($rslt as $key=>$value){
        $row[$key]=$value;
    } 
    $data[]=$row;
}

// Free result
$stmt->free_result();

// Close connections
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Any advice or suggestions are useful, please do contribute and help out even if you are only guessing. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The only thing I would improve here - is to remove last 3 lines (freeing results and closing everything). Everything else is good. I'm sure your senior was wrong. PS: Also I hope `col` column is covered by index and you don't select more than ~25-30% of all the rows

Comment: Thanks for the critique, do you mean remove them incase I need to do another query inside the same script? As I normally then only close $stmt and keep the $mysqli object alive and create another $stmnt2 object to perform my next query on. Also what do you mean "covered by index"? Link to MySQL documentation would be handy :) Thanks

Comment: "Thanks for the critique, do you mean remove them incase I need to do another query inside the same script?" --- no, I mean remove them because you don't need them. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Right ok, thanks. Would calling them have such a massive impact on performance though? From what I read about the methods on PHP.net I can't see either of those draining the CPU... Thanks for the MySQL link also, I shall get reading!

Comment: there is no impact, but why to do anything that makes no sense (in this particular case)? You could perform couple of `$a = 1 + 2;` in the end as well, just because you can :-)

Comment: Although the manual recommends caution, you could try and measure the performance of using `fetch_all`. That way you loose everything after the `execute` statement. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: Very very true, although if I do enough maths I'm sure that WOULD cause a drain on CPU ;)

Comment: IMO, your "some senior" is either pulling yr leg or doesn't no what you are talking about. As @greenlion says, how you frame your _SQL queries_ could hammer the DB engine; how you frame the MySQLi call has immaterial impact on server load for this type of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of code that may be inefficient, the PHP code and the SQL code, or both.

For example, the SQL is a problem if the `col` column isn't indexed in the database.  This puts lots of load on the database because the database has to scan very many rows to answer queries.  If `col` isn't indexed in the given query, then all of the rows in the table would be scanned.  Also, if the value passed in isn't very selective, then many rows will have to be examined, perhaps all of the rows, as MySQL will choose a table scan over an index scan when many rows will be examined.  You will need to become familiar with the MySQL EXPLAIN plan feature to fix your queries, or add indexes to the database to support your queries.

The PHP would be a problem if you followed something like the pattern:

```
select invoice_id from invoices where customer_id = ?
for each invoice_id
   select * from line_items where invoice_id = ?
```

That kind of pattern will lead to "over querying" the database, which puts extra load on it. 
Instead use a join:

```
select li.* from invoices i join line_items li using (invoice_id)
```

Ask your database administrator to turn on the slow query log and then process it with [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html)

You can use pt-query-digest to report on queries that are expensive (take a long time to execute) and also to use it to report by frequency to detect over querying.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I don't normally setup the databases I just query them using PHP so this might not be something that I personally have to fix. I am familiar with joins however, thanks for the pointer but I haven't written anything like that in a LONG time hahaha! From what you can see there's nothing wrong with my PHP though?

Comment: You may want to add instrumentation to your application.  I maintain a PHP instrumentation layer: http://code.google.com/p/instrumentation-for-php